# RSpec - Dealing with a retry inside a rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm currently running into a loop where `retry` gets executed within my test. How can I stub `retry` and still test the code above it?

I have a snippet to catch HostKeyMismatch exceptions:

```
rescue Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch => e
  e.remember_host!
  retry
end
```

My spec:

```
describe "rescues Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch" do
  it "resyncs the ssh keys" do
    Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch.any_instance.should_receive(:remember_host!).and_return(true)
    ssh_class.new.run_ssh_command { raise Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch }
  end
end
```

Error I'm getting:

```
   The message 'remember_host!' was received by #<Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch: Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch> but has already been received by Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch
```

**Update:**

I was able to resolve the issue by adding a counter to the suggested answer below:

```
describe "rescues Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch" do
  it "resyncs the ssh keys" do
    exception = Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch.new
    exception.should_receive(:remember_host!).and_return(true)
    count = 0
    ssh_class.new.run_ssh_command do
      count += 1
      raise exception unless count > 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retry is called on the object on which your run_ssh_command was called.

So

```
describe "rescues Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch" do
  it "resyncs the ssh keys" do
    ssh_instance = ssh_class.new

    Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch.any_instance.should_receive(:remember_host!).and_return(true)
    ssh_instance.should_receive(:retry)

    ssh_instance.run_ssh_command { raise  Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch}
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried your answer verbatim but the final line seems to run in an infinite loop

Comment: @MusannifZahir: I have updated my answer. Please try with that

Comment: Same issue since the run_ssh_command block keeps raising the exception unconditionally. I was able to resolve the issue by adding a counter - the question has been updated with the final solution